# Getting Null list after expecting a result while making a REST-Api call

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm pretty new to using Android and Android Networking and I got stuck. Here is my code:

```
private void getParticipantsForMeeting(Integer id)
    {

        AndroidNetworking.get(LOCALHOST + "/meeting?meetingId={meetingid}")
                .addPathParameter("meetingid", String.valueOf(meeting.getId()))
                .setTag(this)
                .setPriority(Priority.LOW)
                .build()
                .getAsObjectList(User.class, new ParsedRequestListener<List<User>>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(List<User> response) {
                        if (response == null)
                            Log.println(Log.INFO, "GETMEETINGPARTICIPANTS", "No participants found for this meeting");
                        else {
                            meeting.setParticipants(response);
                            Log.println(Log.INFO, "GETMEETINGPARTICIPANTS", "No participants found for this meeting");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError anError) {
                        Log.println(Log.ERROR, "GETMEETINGPARTICIPANTS", "Error while trying to get participants for meeting");
                    }
                });

    }
```

when I am in `onResponse()` method, I get the requested response, but after parsing the method, `meeting.getParticipants()` is still null. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, because other calls are working as expected, except this one. I can't figure out this strange behavior, I have also tried to add the response in a list and return the list, save it as `SharedPreferences` and save it in a static variable, but the problem is still here. Maybe a relevant mention is that issue happens in a fragment and the other calls didn't return a list of objects, but only one object.
Could someone please explain me why I get this error and how can I fix it? You would really help a puddled student!
Edit: here is my Meeting POJO:

```
@Data
public class Meeting implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;

    private Long meetingDate;

    private Boolean deleted;

    private String location;

    private MeetingType meetingType;

    private String title;

    private List<User> participants;

    private String description;

}
```

I have also tried to get a JSONArray, but I get the same issue: it is visible in the onResponse method, but not after parsing it, this is how it looks like now:

```
AndroidNetworking.get(LOCALHOST + "/meeting?meetingId={meetingid}")
                .addPathParameter("meetingid", String.valueOf(meeting.getId()))
                .setTag(this)
                .setPriority(Priority.LOW)
                .build()
                .getAsJSONArray(new JSONArrayRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        if (response == null)
                            Log.println(Log.INFO, "GETMEETINGPARTICIPANTS", "No participants found for this meeting");
                        else {
                            JSONObject jsonObject;
                            Gson gson = new Gson();

                            for (int i=0; i<response.length();i++)
                            {
                                try {
                                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    User user = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), User.class);
                                    users.add(user);

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            Log.println(Log.INFO, "GETMEETINGPARTICIPANTS", "No participants found for this meeting");
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError anError) {

                        Log.println(Log.ERROR, "GETMEETINGPARTICIPANTS", "Error while trying to get participants for meeting");

                    }
                });
```

My method is called in `onCreateView` method.

Comment: maybe look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android)

Comment: Please show us the ** meeting** POJO

Comment: I have edited the post with more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my issue: 
Apparently the method with my Rest call was called only after setting my TextViews, even though it was called before their setters. I think it is caoused because of the asynchronous call. I solved my problem setting the text for my text view inside of onResponse method. I don't believe this is the correct solution, but it's a good work-around for the moment.

```
AndroidNetworking.get(LOCALHOST + "/meeting?meetingId={meetingid}")
                .addPathParameter("meetingid", String.valueOf(id))
                .setPriority(Priority.LOW)
                .build()
                .getAsJSONArray(new JSONArrayRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        if (response == null)
                            Log.println(Log.INFO, "GETMEETINGPARTICIPANTS", "No participants found for this meeting");
                        else {
                            JSONObject jsonObject;
                            Gson gson = new Gson();

                            for (int i=0; i<response.length();i++)
                            {
                                try {
                                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    User user = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), User.class);
                                    users.add(user);

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            show_participants.setText(getParticipantsName(users)); //this worked for me

                            Log.println(Log.INFO, "GETMEETINGPARTICIPANTS", "No participants found for this meeting");
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError anError) {

                        Log.println(Log.ERROR, "GETMEETINGPARTICIPANTS", "Error while trying to get participants for meeting");

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your working with Json. Thats your problem. "the other calls didn't return a list of objects, but only one object." You need to use jsonarray then loop through the array and parse the objects.
Look here,

```
AndroidNetworking.get("https://fierce-cove-29863.herokuapp.com/getAllUsers/{pageNumber}")
    .addPathParameter("pageNumber", "0")
    .addHeaders("token", "1234")
    .setPriority(Priority.LOW)
    .build()
    .getAsJSONArray(new JSONArrayRequestListener() {
    @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                  // do anything with response
                }
```

Comment: Hey @Vahalaru, thank you for your suggestion, I've tried to apply it, but still nothing changed, can you take a look on the edited post?